# Getting "Unsupported Body Payload Object" error when trying to upload file to s3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, backend, formidable

I'm trying to upload a file to s3 that's being sent to my server via REST from my front end.

I'm using React on the frontend and Koa on the backend. (`"koa": "^2.13.0", "koa-body": "^5.0.0"`).

The code on the front end is using a FormData to send the file and an ID associated with which bucket the file should be uploaded to (using GraphQL that makes REST calls):

```
async uploadFile (args) {
            if (!args.file) return args;
            const file = await args.file;
            const configData = new FormData();
            configData.append('file', file.createReadStream());
            configData.append('locationId', args.locationId);

            return await this.post('/model/config', configData);
  }
```

Server side code:

```
// Controller 
const uploadConfig = async (ctx) => {
    const file = ctx.request.files;
    console.log('file', file)
    const {locationId} = ctx.request.body;
    ctx.body = await modelService.uploadConfig(file, locationId);
}


// Model Service

const uploadFile = async (file, path) => {
    const {mimetype} = file;
    console.log('file is: ', file);

    return await s3.upload(file, `${path}/assets/config.rcconfig}`, 'application/octet-stream');
}

exports.uploadConfig = async (file, locationId) => {
    const loc = await getDirLocation(locationId);
    const {LOCATION: uri} = await uploadFile(file, dirname(loc.uri));

    return uri;
}
```

When I log the file in the uploadFile function I get:

```
file is:  {
    file: PersistentFile {
        _events: [Object: null prototype] { error: [Function (anonymous)] },
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        lastModifiedDate: 2022-05-31T17:40:02.850Z,
        filepath: '/tmp/7064b3e99e9cb27282a393200',
        newFilename: '7064b3e99e9cb27282a393200',
        originalFilename: null,
        mimetype: 'application/octet-stream',
        hashAlgorithm: false,
        size: 14372,
        _writeStream: WriteStream {
            fd: null,
            path: '/tmp/7064b3e99e9cb27282a393200',
            flags: 'w',
            mode: 438,
            start: undefined,
            pos: undefined,
            bytesWritten: 14372,
            closed: true,
            _writableState: [WritableState],
            _events: [Object: null prototype],
            _eventsCount: 1,
            _maxListeners: undefined,
            [Symbol(kFs)]: [Object],
            [Symbol(kIsPerformingIO)]: false,
            [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
        },
        hash: null,
        [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    }
}
```

When I try to upload the file to s3 I get an error

> App Error: Unsupported body payload object body: "", stack: Error: Unsupported body payload object

I can log the file (as post above) so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error and how to resolve it so I can upload my file.

I'd appreciate any help that would get me closer to getting my file uploaded to s3!
Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: After some more research, I think my issue might be with Formidable. I'm using koa-body which is dependent on `"@types/formidable": "^2.0.4"` and `"formidable": "^2.0.1"`

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file. Write the data from the file passed to your server to the new file. Upload that new file to s3.

Try that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).